# Unable to append (read and write) text file with php. Using fopen() and fwrite() together

Tags: php

I recently installed Apache, PHP and started working on a small project.

I have the following code.

```
<?php 
$tim=time();
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$ipadd=$tim."IPaddress".$ip;

$fp="user_log.txt";// file address

$myfilea = fopen($fp,"a");//open file

fwrite($myfilea,$ipadd.PHP_EOL);//add data to file
echo fread($myfilea,filesize($fp));//read file
fclose($myfilea);//close file
?>
```

Here is what I can do... I can either use "a" mode to add text or I can use "r" mode to read text. I cant do both. I tried using "a+","r+","ar" etc.

Did I miss something during my setup ???

I am running this on windows 8.1.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why do you think you "can't do both" (`a+`)?

Comment: I know I should be able to but for some reason I am unable to do it . I have tried a+

Comment: Have you checked your error logs?

Comment: There are no errors in log.

Comment: it's the file pointer...think "cassette tape"...you need to rewind it since you added to the end.  you're looking at the end, so you can't read something before it.

Comment: I removed "(solved)" from the question's title. Accepting an answer is enough to mark it as such; no further action is needed on your part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rewind the file pointer.

```
$tim = time();
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$ipadd = $tim.'IPaddress'.$ip;

// file address
$fp = 'user_log.txt';

//open file
$myfilea = fopen($fp, 'a+');

//add data to file
fwrite($myfilea, $ipadd.PHP_EOL);

// your file pointer is at the end of the file now
// so rewind before you read
rewind($myfilea);

//read file
echo fread($myfilea, filesize($fp));
//close file
fclose($myfilea);
```

Comment: Thanks bro. rewind() solves it. I though file would be read from beginning when you call fread() automatically. I was basically reading from end of file. Thanks a Ton

Comment: The "+" in $myfilea = fopen($fp, 'a+'); also was necessary.

I would recomend $tim=date("Ymdis"); to get a string with Year month day minute second. I use this in my logs.

Comment: Indeed - without the "a+" you wont' be able to read the file as per [the documentation on fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, use **[file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)**

`file_put_contents` = Write a string to a file

```
$fp="user_log.txt";
$tim=time();
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$ipadd=$tim."IPaddress".$ip;
$myfile = file_put_contents($fp, $ipadd.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

And for your code try this, it will check able to open file or not

```
fopen("logs.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is what I was going to do. But I still wanted to know whats going on.

Comment: why would you not use `file_get_contents` if you used `file_put_contents`?